# c-fill a one dimensional array with for loop

Tags: arrays, c, fill

I can understand the first solution.But in the second solution i am confused about the way `scanf`, accept 4 values at the same time and apply them to the `for` loop.

```
//first solution
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int pin[4],i;
    
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        printf("Give value: ");
        scanf("%d", &pin[i]);
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

```
//second solution
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int pin[4],i;
    
    printf("Give 4 values: ");
    
    for(i=0; i<4; i++){
        
        scanf("%d", &pin[i]);
    }
  
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's confusing and what's the difference? And please fix the formatting.

Comment: Try answering `"42 -1 2021 0<ENTER>"` with the 1st example (after the first print).

Comment: Ok i can now see that solution 1 and 2 are exactly the same thing.But the part that confuses me, is that i can give 4 values at the same time .Doesn't make sense to me because the scanf is inside the for loop and it has to be executed 4 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is only that in the first example there is a printf that asks you for the input values at every iteration of the cycle while in the first example there is a printf (only one) before the cycle.

The operation that matters (the scanf) is exactly the same in the two examples.

Answer (score 0):

The `scanf` commamd does not read four values at the same time.

This is an example of a **loop**: a piece of code that does the same thing multiple times.

```
for(i=0; i<4; i++){
    
    scanf("%d", &pin[i]);
}
```

What the `for` statement does is, first initialize `i` to zero, then check that `i` is less than four, then, execute the code within its curly braces. That's the `scanf` statement, which attempts to read an integer to the address specified by `&pin[i]`. Since `i` is zero, that means, the address of `pin[0]`, which is the first element of the array `pin`.

After the `scanf` executes (and whether or not it succeeds, which is something you may want to look into) the `for` statement increments the value of `i`, checks that it is still less than four, and executes the block of code between the braces again. This time, the `scanf` statement attempts to read to `pin[1]`.

The loop executes two more times, potentially storing integers in `pin[2]` and `pin[3]` before terminating just after incrementing `i` to 4.